# argument should be integer or None, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Tags: python, integer, arguments

I tried to read the csv file and list its elements, but error causes.
The purpose of this code is for learning and testing neural networks for image classification. I tried to read the file, that has the result as its first line and from second line on its data are all about images

```
test_data_file = open("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Neural_Networks\\mnist_test.csv", 'r')
test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines(test_data_file)  
test_data_file.close()

socrecard = []

for record in test_data_list:
    all_values = record.split(',')
    correct_label = int(all_values[0])
    inputs = (numpy.asfarry(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 *0.99) + 0.01
    outpus = n.query(inputs)
    label = numpy.argmax(outpus)

    if (label == correct_label):
        scorecard.append(1)

    else:
       scorecard.append(0)
    pass
pass

scorecard_array = numpy.asarray(socrecard)
print ("performace= ", socrecard_array.sum()/scorecard_array.size)

`enter code here`Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 1, in 
    runfile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Neural_Networks/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Desktop/Neural_Networks')

File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Neural_Networks/test.py", line 69, in 
    training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines(training_data_file)

TypeError: argument should be integer or None, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: You don't need to pass an arguments to file.readlines - just do `test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines()`